# Authors details such as social media links, emails etc → Is this Meta or something else?

Tags: functions, custom-field, widgets, author, user-meta

The author section of my first **WordPress theme** is currently **hard coded in HTML**.

See the live website [here](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/8/).

[This One.](https://www.screencast.com/t/j7ZZxDUFsac)

These **social media Icons** and the link associated with them are not provided in the backend author dashboard by default and they need to be coded.[image]

Can someone guide me how to?

Is this feature will also come under meta category?

---

Sir, I have one more confusion which part of the code you have written will be used for actually printing the social media URL's that we have saved in the author's dashboard in the backend.

For the sake of simplifying my query, I am putting here my author's code to be displayed on the front end →

```
<div class="author-box">
    <div class="author-image">
        <img src="http://blog.blogeto.com/html/images/author_profile.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="author-description">
        <h2>
            <!-- AUTHORS NAME --> <?php the_author(); ?>
            <!-- <a href="<?php get_author_posts_url(); ?>"><?php the_author() ?></a> -->
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </h2>
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.<a href="#">Read More</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="author-category">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CATEGORY 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add user contact methods using the `user_contactmethods` filter in your theme's `functions.php` or via a plugin:

User contact method entries are stored in the `wp_usermeta` table. The URL field is special; it's stored in the `user_url` field in the `wp_users` table.

```
// Add user contact methods
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods','wpse_user_contactmethods', 10, 1 );
function wpse_user_contactmethods( $contact_methods ) {
    $contact_methods['facebook'] = __( 'Facebook URL', 'text_domain'    );
    $contact_methods['twitter']  = __( 'Twitter URL', 'text_domain' );
    $contact_methods['linkedin'] = __( 'LinkedIn URL', 'text_domain'    );
    $contact_methods['youtube']  = __( 'YouTube URL', 'text_domain' );

    return $contact_methods;
}
```

Output the links in your template file:

```
<div class="author-box">
    <div class="author-image">
        <img src="http://blog.blogeto.com/html/images/author_profile.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="author-description">
        <h2>
        <!-- AUTHORS NAME --> <?php the_author(); ?>
        <!-- <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author() ?></a> -->
            <?php 
                // Get the id of the post's author.
                $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );

                // Get WP_User object for the author.
                $author_userdata = get_userdata( $author_id );

                // Get the author's website. It's stored in the wp_users table in the user_url field.
                $author_website = $author_userdata->data->user_url;

                // Get the rest of the author links. These are stored in the 
                // wp_usermeta table by the key assigned in wpse_user_contactmethods()
                $author_facebook = get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', $author_id );
                $author_twitter  = get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $author_id  );
                $author_linkedin = get_the_author_meta( 'linkedin', $author_id );
                $author_youtube  = get_the_author_meta( 'youtube', $author_id  );

                // Output the user's social links if they have values.
                if ( $author_website ) {
                        printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                                esc_url( $author_website )
                        );
                }

                if ( $author_facebook ) {
                        printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                                esc_url( $author_facebook )
                        );
                }

                if ( $author_twitter ) {
                        printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                                esc_url( $author_twitter )
                        );
                }

                if ( $author_linkedin ) {
                        printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                                esc_url( $author_linkedin )
                        );
                }

                if ( $author_youtube ) {
                        printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                                esc_url( $author_youtube )
                        );
                }
            ?>
        </h2>
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.   <a href="#">Read More</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="author-category">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="">CATEGORY 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CATEGORY 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CATEGORY 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CATEGORY 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CATEGORY 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be also achieved through this kind of method → http://wpengineer.com/2173/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/

Comment: Yes, that might be more helpful when creating non text input fields or something more custom.

Comment: Sir, There is one confusion Left I have uploaded my question a little bit. My confusion was regarding where should I publish or print the values saved in the back-end.

Comment: I've update the answer so that it uses your HTML. (This is plain PHP and nothing WordPress specific at this point.) You'll probably want to save this code in a dedicated template part include this template file from your single post template.

Comment: Sir, If and only If you ever think that my posts will be beneficial to future users. Please do encourage me with the upvotes on my posts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those fields will be user meta. And for storing social links of a user you'll have to add custom user meta.

Here's developer's documentation for your reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/

Note: See example code for better understanding.

Comment: If I would have the example code I wouldn't have posted the question for the help.

Comment: Example code is in the link I attached.