# How to avoid one code multiple times instead do that through some function? Shortcode, but I think shortcode is not used in main theme's core files?

Tags: shortcode, author, user-meta

I posted a question here on the [StackExchange Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266429/authors-details-such-as-social-media-links-emails-etc-%E2%86%92-is-this-meta-or-somethi). The question was successfully answered.

I want to avoid copy pasting one code multiple times in different php files such as content.php or may be that code is again wanted in some sidebar area etc.

Is shortcode the solution to avoid pasting it multiple times? But I think shortcodes are used on WordPress editor, not the core php files?

what is the solution?

By the way the full code that I do not want to repeat copy paste is this one →

```
<?php 
            // Get the id of the post's author.
            $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );

            // Get WP_User object for the author.
            $author_userdata = get_userdata( $author_id );

            // Get the author's website. It's stored in the wp_users table in the user_url field.
            $author_website = $author_userdata->data->user_url;

            // Get the rest of the author links. These are stored in the 
            // wp_usermeta table by the key assigned in wpse_user_contactmethods()
            $author_facebook = get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', $author_id );
            $author_twitter  = get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $author_id  );
            $author_linkedin = get_the_author_meta( 'linkedin', $author_id );
            $author_youtube  = get_the_author_meta( 'youtube', $author_id  );

            // Output the user's social links if they have values.
            if ( $author_website ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                            esc_url( $author_website )
                    );
            }

            if ( $author_facebook ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                            esc_url( $author_facebook )
                    );
            }

            if ( $author_twitter ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                            esc_url( $author_twitter )
                    );
            }

            if ( $author_linkedin ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                            esc_url( $author_linkedin )
                    );
            }

            if ( $author_youtube ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
                            esc_url( $author_youtube )
                    );
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP's includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) like this:

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/components/authorSocials.php';
```

but you should remember about providing the data to your component. Since the idea is that you will you use it in different places, not always the default values will be available and will be the right ones, so you should add some more code to this solution:

```
$user_id = assign_your_user_id_here();
include dirname(__FILE__).'/components/authorSocials.php';
```

then in your "component" do:

```
<?php 
    // Get the id of the post's author.
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID', $user_id);

    .....
?>
```

Comment: `$user_id = assign_your_user_id_here();` → I didn't get this? the users ids should be pulled dynamically that is why we use content managemnt system like wordpress. Isn't it?

Comment: is there any process to convert this into a function orf code snippet?

Comment: It all depends where you will use it, I meant that you should be aware that when using includes/snippets doing just `get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )` could lead sometimes to unpredictable results and it better to be safe with providing all arguments for instance `get_the_author_meta( 'ID', $author_id );`. To put it in a function you need to jus wrap the snipped in `function authorSocials($post) { ... }` and possibly changing the `printf's` into assignments to a variable returned by the function.

Comment: Jusr 2-3 months experience didn't understand sir. can you please simplify.